# Assign pointed to value to other pointed to value

Tags: c, pointers

So I have a binary tree with nodes as shown below

```
typedef struct N {
    int num;
    struct N *left;
    struct N *right;
}
```

I create root node and store it in a variable.

```
N *root = rootNode;
```

Now in the course my program I want to add some new node (newNode with value of X) to this tree. My code is as follows

```
N* node = root;
while (node) {
    node = node->left;
}
node = newNode;
printf("%s\n",node->data);
printf("%s\n",root->left->data);
```

But while node->data is X root->left->data is still NULL. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `node = newNode;` means nothing to the pointer that actually got you there. A fairly easy way to do what you want uses a pointer-to-pointer, and as a bonus alleviates special-casing root insertions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because when you quit the while() node is set to NULL;

so you're assigning a new value to something NULL, but in the last node of your tree , node->left is still set to NULL.

you need to set the condition as follows:

```
while (node->left!=NULL) { /* we stop at the last node (leaf) of the       tree)*/
node = node->left;
}

node->left=newnode; /*( we set a child to the previous leaf of our tree )*/
```